# Git failed to push (LFS upload missing objects)

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

I’ve been using Gitlab with LFS just fine for a while now but somehow ran into this problem today:

```
me@some-PC MINGW32 /b/Unity Projects/Platballer (master)
$ git push
LFS upload missing objects: (32/33), 30 MB | 0 B/s
Uploading LFS objects:  97% (32/33), 30 MB | 0 B/s, done
  (missing) Assets/External Assets/TimelineEvents/setup-guide.pdf (6ef8ef61e49821309de416925bf4e068ebb10a57f3398cb926e967eeb90cf034)
Counting objects: 401, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (400/400), done.
Writing objects: 100% (401/401), 1.40 MiB | 9.56 MiB/s, done.
Total 401 (delta 177), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (177/177), completed with 31 local objects.
remote: GitLab: LFS objects are missing. Ensure LFS is properly set up or try a manual "git lfs push --all".
To arvzrg.asuscomm.com:arvz/platballer.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@link.someurlcom:me/project.git'
```

So I did what they said and ran **git lfs push --all origin master**
which gives me:

```
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (330/331), 52 MB | 0 B/s, done
LFS upload missing objects:
  (missing) Assets/External Assets/TimelineEvents/setup-guide.pdf (6ef8ef61e49821309de416925bf4e068ebb10a57f3398cb926e967eeb90cf034)
```

It seems like that did whatever needed doing, right? So I tried pushing again, but I still get the exact same problem I did before.

I'm running my own installation of GitLab on a server on my network.

What else can I do here?

Comment: Also tried doing `$ git lfs fsck` which just gives me `Git LFS fsck OK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this is similar to [gitlab-org/gitlab-ce issue 40616](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40616#note_68864545):

> I've verified that it is possible to push to GitLab if the LFS objects are stored elsewhere, but LFS must be disabled for the project so that the LFS validation is disabled.
>
> Disabled LFS for the project using the API (I'm using HTTPie)
>
> `http PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<id> name=<project-name> lfs_enabled=false Private-Token:<your token>`
>
> Add the `lfs.url` to the lfs config (for example GitHub)
>
> ```
> git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url https://github.com/<user>/<project>.git/info/lfs
> ```
>
> Push to GitLab should now work

Comment: @mathtick Not sure actually